# data upload error: id value of incorrect type

Tags: data-loader, data, upload

A member of our support team gave me a list of 100 Account ID's and their associated 'Customer Success Manager' in text form. I was asked to upload this data to salesforce, using Data Loader.

I asked if I could have the ID of each customer success manager, but was informed that it was not available from the account object.

When I tried to upload the data, I received this message on each of the accounts:

> **Customer Success Manager: id value of incorrect type:** *'name'*

It would appear I need to provide an ID for each of the customer success managers, but how to get that, Im not sure.

Details of the custom Customer Success Manager field:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above screenshot it seems that '**Customer Success Manager**' is a **lookup** to the **User Object**. What you can do is, since you have the Customer Success Manager in name form, you could run a **query** for those against the **User object** and **get the Ids** for each of those names. Then in your initial AccountId->Customer Success Manager Name, replace the name with the newly obtained Id and run the update again. Hope it helps.